# Start / execute XML Test Node from vector CANoe object

Tags: c#, canoe, comobject, test-environments

The following is the code which was used:

```
    CANoe.Application mCANoeApp;
    CANoe.Measurement mCANalyzerMeasurement;
    CANoe.Nodes mCANoeNodes;
    CANoe.Node mCANoeNode;
    CANoe.Configuration mConfig;
    CANoe.TestModules mTestModules;
    CANoe.TestSetup mTestSetup;
    CANoe.TestEnvironments mtestEnvironments;
    CANoe.TSTestModule mTSmodule;
    CANoe.SimulationSetup msimulationSetup;
    CANoe.Buses mCanoebuses;
    mCANoeApp = new CANoe.Application();   
    //invoke delegate
                mCANoeApp.OnOpen += mCANoeApp_OnOpen;
                

                mCANoeApp.Open(cfgfiles[0], true, true); //open cfg 
                mCANalyzerMeasurement = (CANoe.Measurement)mCANoeApp.Measurement;

                  mCANalyzerMeasurement.OnStart += mCANalyzerMeasurement_OnStart;
                  mCANalyzerMeasurement.OnStop += mCANalyzerMeasurement_OnStop;
            //invoke onStart Measurement
                mCANalyzerMeasurement.OnStart += mCANalyzerMeasurement_OnStart;
                //Start the measurement ..........
                mCANalyzerMeasurement.Start(); //run
                str = "Canoe measurement started..." + "\n";
                sb.Append(str);


                while (!mCANalyzerMeasurement.Running)
                {
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
                }
             
                // multiple nodes
                msimulationSetup = (CANoe.SimulationSetup)mCANoeApp.Configuration.SimulationSetup; 

                mCANoeNodes = (CANoe.Nodes)msimulationSetup.Nodes;
                toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "check for TestNode..." + "\n";
                strTestNodeToTest = "TestNode"; //This is an XML TestNode
                sb.Append(toolStripStatusLabel1.Text);

                for (int i=1;i< mCANoeNodes.Count;i++)
                {
                    
                str = "Nodes Count: "+ mCANoeNodes.Count.ToString()+" index:" +i.ToString() + "\n";
                    sb.Append(str);
                toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "mCANoeNodes[i].Name:? " + mCANoeNodes[i].Name + "\n"; 
                    sb.Append(toolStripStatusLabel1.Text);

                    if (mCANoeNodes[i].Name == strTestNodeToTest)
                    {

                        mCANoeNodes[i].Active = true;

                        toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Before start NM " + "\n";
                        sb.Append(str);

                        
                        ((CANoe.Node)mCANoeNodes[i]).StartNM(); //Is this correct

                        
                        toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "After start NM " + "\n";
                        sb.Append(toolStripStatusLabel1.Text);

                      
                        break;

                    }
                }

  ((CANoe.Node)mCANoeNodes[i]).StartNM(); //Is this correct
```

I would like to start the measurement automatically which is happening but later I would like to run the
XML test node which I could not do that and is giving the below error.
This function is returning error saying "Unable to case COM object of type System.__Comobject" to interface type CANoe.Node

Please let us know how to cast the Node and run the XML testnode.

Is there any other way to run it from TestEnvironment ?
Please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to run a Test Node using COM interface. For this, you need add your test module to a Test Environment (not simulation setup).

Once you do this change, you can use the `ExecuteAll` or `Start` methods to start all modules or a particular module.